# How to make an SVG text glitch effect affect an SVG path instead

Tags: html, animation, svg, effect

I'm using an SVG effect to produce a glitch effect on a bit of text, but I want it to effect the logo instead. The logo is also SVG, using a path.

[Here is the website showing the effect, as you can see the text is glitched rather than the diamond.](http://www.royalarcademusic.co.uk/)

Here is the code:

The Text:

```
                <svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="800px" height="110px" viewBox="0 0 800 110" style="margin-left: 116px;">
<style type="text/css">

<![CDATA[

    text {
        filter: url(#filter);
        fill: white;
        font-size: 100px;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            }
]]>
</style>
    <defs>

        <filter id="filter">
            <feFlood flood-color="black" result="black" />
            <feFlood flood-color="red" result="flood1" />
            <feFlood flood-color="limegreen" result="flood2" />
            <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" dx="3" dy="0" result="off1a"/>
            <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" dx="2" dy="0" result="off1b"/>
            <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" dx="-3" dy="0" result="off2a"/>
            <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" dx="-2" dy="0" result="off2b"/>
            <feComposite in="flood1" in2="off1a" operator="in"  result="comp1" />
            <feComposite in="flood2" in2="off2a" operator="in" result="comp2" />

            <feMerge x="0" width="100%" result="merge1">
                <feMergeNode in = "black" />
                <feMergeNode in = "comp1" />
                <feMergeNode in = "off1b" />

                <animate 
                    attributeName="y" 
                    id = "y"
                    dur ="4s"

                    values = '104px; 104px; 30px; 105px; 30px; 2px; 2px; 50px; 40px; 105px; 105px; 20px; 6ßpx; 40px; 104px; 40px; 70px; 10px; 30px; 104px; 102px'

                    keyTimes = '0; 0.362; 0.368; 0.421; 0.440; 0.477; 0.518; 0.564; 0.593; 0.613; 0.644; 0.693; 0.721; 0.736; 0.772; 0.818; 0.844; 0.894; 0.925; 0.939; 1'

                    repeatCount = "indefinite" />

                <animate attributeName="height" 
                    id = "h" 
                    dur ="4s"

                    values = '10px; 0px; 10px; 30px; 50px; 0px; 10px; 0px; 0px; 0px; 10px; 50px; 40px; 0px; 0px; 0px; 40px; 30px; 10px; 0px; 50px'

                    keyTimes = '0; 0.362; 0.368; 0.421; 0.440; 0.477; 0.518; 0.564; 0.593; 0.613; 0.644; 0.693; 0.721; 0.736; 0.772; 0.818; 0.844; 0.894; 0.925; 0.939; 1'

                    repeatCount = "indefinite" />
            </feMerge>


            <feMerge x="0" width="100%" y="60px" height="65px" result="merge2">
                <feMergeNode in = "black" />
                <feMergeNode in = "comp2" />
                <feMergeNode in = "off2b" />

                <animate attributeName="y" 
                    id = "y"
                    dur ="4s"
                    values = '103px; 104px; 69px; 53px; 42px; 104px; 78px; 89px; 96px; 100px; 67px; 50px; 96px; 66px; 88px; 42px; 13px; 100px; 100px; 104px;' 

                    keyTimes = '0; 0.055; 0.100; 0.125; 0.159; 0.182; 0.202; 0.236; 0.268; 0.326; 0.357; 0.400; 0.408; 0.461; 0.493; 0.513; 0.548; 0.577; 0.613; 1'

                    repeatCount = "indefinite" />

                <animate attributeName="height" 
                    id = "h"
                    dur = "4s"

                    values = '0px; 0px; 0px; 16px; 16px; 12px; 12px; 0px; 0px; 5px; 10px; 22px; 33px; 11px; 0px; 0px; 10px'

                    keyTimes = '0; 0.055; 0.100; 0.125; 0.159; 0.182; 0.202; 0.236; 0.268; 0.326; 0.357; 0.400; 0.408; 0.461; 0.493; 0.513;  1'

                    repeatCount = "indefinite" />
            </feMerge>

            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />  

                <feMergeNode in="merge1" /> 
            <feMergeNode in="merge2" />

            </feMerge>
        </filter>

    </defs>

<g>
    <text x="0" y="100">ROYAL ARCADE</text>

    </g>
</svg>
```

The Diamond:

```
    <div style="margin-top: -30px;">
                    <div class="glitch">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="200px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 1136.943 907.455" enable-background="new 0 0 1136.943 907.455"
     xml:space="preserve">
     <defs>
     <linearGradient id="rgrad__uniqueID_756c7399" x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="46%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
   <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 255, 244); stop-opacity:1"></stop>
   <stop offset="46%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 74, 255); stop-opacity:1"></stop>
   <stop offset="98%" style="stop-color:rgb(127, 46, 208); stop-opacity:1"></stop>
</linearGradient>
     </defs>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#rgrad__uniqueID_756c7399)" d="M970.566,15.158H166.187L8.808,259.969v8.744l555.197,629.514
    h8.743l555.196-625.142v-13.116L970.566,15.158z M887.504,58.875l-87.433,139.892L642.694,58.875H887.504z M765.099,238.112H371.652
    L568.376,54.503L765.099,238.112z M494.059,58.875l-153.007,135.52l-87.433-135.52H494.059z M192.417,58.875l113.662,179.237H78.754
    L192.417,58.875z M78.754,281.828h236.068L515.917,771.45L78.754,281.828z M568.376,771.45L367.281,281.828h402.19L568.376,771.45z
     M620.835,771.45L821.93,281.828h236.068L620.835,771.45z M830.673,238.112L944.336,58.875l113.662,179.237H830.673z"/>
</svg>
                    </div>
```

So to summarise, how do I make the glitch effect work on the Diamond SVG rather than the text?

Thanks in advance

Comment: set the `filter` attribute on the diamond `<path>` to `"url(#filter)"`. Note you will probably need to tweak the filter since it is done with the absolute sizes of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kaiido says, all you really need to do is apply the same filter to your logo. It needs a bit of resizing to make it fit properly, and it looks better if you tone down the green and red fill colours. But otherwise, nothing much has changed:

```html
<svg width="200" height="160" viewBox="0 0 200 160">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="46%" y2="100%"
        gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 255, 244); stop-opacity:1"></stop>
      <stop offset="46%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 74, 255); stop-opacity:1"></stop>
      <stop offset="98%" style="stop-color:rgb(127, 46, 208); stop-opacity:1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feFlood flood-color="black" result="black"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="darkred" result="flood1"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="darkgreen" result="flood2"/>
      <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" dx="3" dy="0" result="off1a"/>
      <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" dx="2" dy="0" result="off1b"/>
      <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" dx="-3" dy="0" result="off2a"/>
      <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" dx="-2" dy="0" result="off2b"/>
      <feComposite in="flood1" in2="off1a" operator="in"  result="comp1"/>
      <feComposite in="flood2" in2="off2a" operator="in" result="comp2"/>
      <feMerge x="0" width="100%" result="merge1">
        <feMergeNode in="black"/>
        <feMergeNode in="comp1"/>
        <feMergeNode in="off1b"/>
        <animate attributeName="y" id="y" dur ="4s"
            values="151px; 151px; 44px; 153px; 44px; 3px; 3px; 73px; 58px; 153px; 153px;
                29px; 9ßpx; 58px; 151px; 58px; 102px; 15px; 44px; 151px; 148px"
            keyTimes="0; 0.362; 0.368; 0.421; 0.440; 0.477; 0.518; 0.564; 0.593; 0.613;
                0.644; 0.693; 0.721; 0.736; 0.772; 0.818; 0.844; 0.894; 0.925; 0.939; 1"
            repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="height" id="h" dur ="4s"
            values="15px; 0px; 15px; 44px; 73px; 0px; 15px; 0px; 0px; 0px; 15px; 73px;
                58px; 0px; 0px; 0px; 58px; 44px; 15px; 0px; 73px"
            keyTimes="0; 0.362; 0.368; 0.421; 0.440; 0.477; 0.518; 0.564; 0.593; 0.613;
                0.644; 0.693; 0.721; 0.736; 0.772; 0.818; 0.844; 0.894; 0.925; 0.939; 1"
            repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </feMerge>
      <feMerge x="0" width="100%" y="87px" height="95px" result="merge2">
        <feMergeNode in="black"/>
        <feMergeNode in="comp2"/>
        <feMergeNode in="off2b"/>
        <animate attributeName="y" id="y" dur ="4s"
            values="150px; 151px; 100px; 77px; 61px; 151px; 113px; 129px; 140px; 145px;
                97px; 73px; 140px; 96px; 128px; 61px; 19px; 145px; 145px; 151px;" 
            keyTimes="0; 0.055; 0.100; 0.125; 0.159; 0.182; 0.202; 0.236; 0.268; 0.326;
                0.357; 0.400; 0.408; 0.461; 0.493; 0.513; 0.548; 0.577; 0.613; 1"
            repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <animate attributeName="height" id="h" dur="4s"
            values="0px; 0px; 0px; 23px; 23px; 17px; 17px; 0px; 0px; 7px; 15px; 32px;
                48px; 16px; 0px; 0px; 15px"
            keyTimes="0; 0.055; 0.100; 0.125; 0.159; 0.182; 0.202; 0.236; 0.268; 0.326;
                0.357; 0.400; 0.408; 0.461; 0.493; 0.513; 1"
            repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </feMerge>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>  
        <feMergeNode in="merge1"/> 
        <feMergeNode in="merge2"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="160" fill="#000" stroke="none"/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#grad)" d="M170.73 2.67H29.23L1.55 45.73v1.54l97.66
      110.74h1.54l97.66-109.97v-2.31L170.73 2.67zM156.12 10.36l-15.38 24.61L113.06 10.36H
      156.12zM134.59 41.89H65.38L99.98 9.59L134.59 41.89zM86.91 10.36l-26.92 23.84l-15.38
      -23.84H86.91zM33.85 10.36l19.99 31.53H13.85L33.85 10.36zM13.85 49.58h41.53L90.76
      135.71L13.85 49.58zM99.98 135.71L64.61 49.58h70.75L99.98 135.71zM109.21 135.71L
      144.59 49.58h41.53L109.21 135.71zM146.12 41.89L166.12 10.36l19.99 31.53H146.12z"
      filter="url(#filter)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @S.Brown At SO they are here to help but all they ask is that you mark the answer. Thanks. Just check the check mark